# Android Swipe View with Tabs adding additional fragments to tab fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, tabs

I have this working swimmingly and it's exactly what I needed:

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

My setup is basically the same; an activity with two nested tabs (fragments), like so:

```
public class StopActivity extends Activity
{
  ...
    public static class EnRouteFragment extends Fragment
    {
      ...
    }

    public static class OnSiteFragment extends Fragment
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

However, now I'd like to add some reusable UI Fragments to the tab/view Fragments therein. I'm relatively new to Android but haven't had any problem adding a Fragment to a plain view, otherwise. In addition to my setup above, I created a simple fragment:

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Pretty basic layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tripText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Trip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/tripSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Space android:layout_width="20dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/stopNoText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop #"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/stopNoSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

...and add it to the first tab/fragment (corresponding layout for "EnRouteFragment" above) :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.me.mobile.StopActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >


    <fragment android:name="com.me.mobile.fragment.DetailsFragment"
              android:id="@+id/detailsFragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get the following exception:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.me.mobile/com.me.mobile.StopActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment
>   com.me.mobile.fragment.DetailsFragment did not create a view.     at
>   android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4809)     at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)

Any clues would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you inflate your view in the `DetailsFragment` if you return the view of superclass? This does not make any sense. You shoud do following

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment
{
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_details, container, false);

    return view;
    }
}
```